# Confusion regarding conditional distribution of the product of gaussian process with a normal

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, gaussian-process

I am getting confused regarding a simple problem. Say: $$Y = WX$$

where $W$ is a $p \times q$ weight matrix with each row distributed as $W_i = \mathbf{N(0,I)}$, and $X$ is a $q\times n$ matrix with each row a Gaussian process denoted as $\mathcal{GP}(M(\mathbf{X_i}),C(\mathbf{X_i},\mathbf{X_i}))$. $M(\bullet)$ is the mean function and $C(\bullet,\bullet)$ is the covariance function.

I am a bit confused with the distribution of $Y$, specifically between $p(Y)$ and $p(Y| W,X)$.
Intuitively $p(Y| W,X)$ should be $N(WX,K)$ where $K = \sum{w_i^2C_i}$. However, it seems that this should be the distribution of $p(Y)$ and not of $p(Y| W,X)$ since W and X should be considered known at this moment and hence distribution should change to $N(WX,0)$. 
I have problems with that reasoning since $W$ and $X$ still are noisy and hence it seems obvious to me that even though we are conditioning on them, the resulting distribution should reflect the noise around their values.

Comment: If $Y=WX$, then $Y$ is completely determined given $W$ and $X$, so the distribution is trivial: $p(Y|W,X) = \delta_{p,n}(Y-WX)$.

Comment: In regression, we generally do not consider the distributional properties of $X$ but consider them fixed as a part of the experimental design. Similarly, weights are usually never considered to even be random variables (except in some very advanced Bayesian applications).

Comment: I do not understand this statement: "W and X still are noisy and hence it seems obvious to me that even though we are conditioning on them, the resulting distribution should reflect the noise around their values." If you condition Y on, say, X, then you get the conditional distribution f(Y|X) of Y given a specific value of X. Given that X may be a random variable itself, you can use f(Y|X) to trace how the conditional distribution of Y changes with X. But "conditioning on X" means keeping X fixed at a specific value.